# Is it possible to post data to an html form without it being in a key-value collection?

Tags: forms, post, key-value

I am wondering if it is possible to post data without using the standard form's key-value pair collection. I'd like to just send my data without having to deal with the HTML form's dictionary of data.

Is this possible using JavaScript or any other means?

I am using ASP.NET MVC, but I don't believe this makes a difference for this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Sure. Imagine posting with XHR.**

With XHR, there is no [HTML Form Encoding](http://docs.bulletinwireless.net/display/GLOSS/HTML+Form+Encoding) to deal with. That is, with XHR, one *can* post whatever data is desired (such as some JSON, a base64 encoding of an image, or even a simulated form encoding) and it won't be framed as with a normal form submission. The most simple (and "raw") way of processing XHR requests (in ASP.NET) is to use [PageMethods, see links](http://forums.asp.net/t/1662003.aspx/1?Page+Methods).

Going through the "form submit" route *requires the browser* to abide by the [HTML Form Encoding](http://docs.bulletinwireless.net/display/GLOSS/HTML+Form+Encoding) (think of the poor back-end and how confused it would get!) as this is "just how HTML works" on a submit. It would be possible to shove all the data to send (after serialization) into a hidden field (which would still honor HTML Form Encoding), but this really sounds like an X-Y question. (That is, if the form collection isn't easy to deal with -- why not? In ASP.NET, using Controls will hide the details).

Happy coding.